# media query not being applied @media screen and (max-width:960px}

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

On [this page](http://test.doig.com.au/br/layout.html), I have layout:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
        ...
  </div>
</body>
```

and CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 1em auto;   
}
@media screen and (max-width:960px} {
    #container {
        width: 100%;
    }   
}
```

However, when I view the page in Firefox responsive view, the #container does not shrink to 100% width when the view port is less than 961px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the } that is after the (max-width:960px} to be a )